# Modules paths set is empty in Liferay

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, liferay-6

I keep seeing this exception in the logs and can't figure out what's causing it apart from that's it's thrown by ComboServlet

```
13:06:01,329 ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-410][ComboServlet:80] com.liferay.portal.ModulePathSetException: Modules paths set is empty
com.liferay.portal.ModulePathSetException: Modules paths set is empty
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ComboServlet.doService(ComboServlet.java:114)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ComboServlet.service(ComboServlet.java:77)
...
13:54:52,783 ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-3][status_jsp:753] Modules paths set is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ComboServlet` minifies and combines JS and CSS files. To do that it needs the path of the files that it should combine.

An URL could look like this: `http://.../combo/?browserId=other&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6200&t=1481621626000&/html/js/liferay/language.js&/html/js/aui/transition/transition-min.js`

The meaning of the parameters:

- `b`: The version of Liferay
- `browserId`: The browser, as identified by Liferay
- `minifierType`: `css` resp. `js`
- `languageId`: The locale of the current user
- `t`: The last modification of the resources or of your theme as timestamp

All other parameters are expected to be the path to the files to combine and minify. In my example `/html/js/liferay/language.js` and `/html/js/aui/transition/transition-min.js`.

If there is no file given as parameter, the `Modules paths set is empty` is the result. It should be easy for you to find the responsible requests in your access log.

(Extracted from the Liferay sources, especially `portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/servlet/ComboServlet.java` and `portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalImpl.java`)

Comment: The url doesn't show in the logs. All I can see is the exception.

Comment: The access log is _not_ the Liferay log. The access log is something you can turn on in your webserver to log all or specific requests. See the documentation of your webserver (Tomcat, JBoss, Apache, ...). You could try as well to configure the logging of Liferay to output the current URL - but I've never tried that.